# What is the difference between ANSI C 89 and C that supports by C++?

Tags: c++, c, c89

I know there are some difference between ANSI C 89 and C that supports by C++.

for example in ANSI C 89, you should declare variables at first line of blocks.

or when you want to declare `struct` variables, you should use `struct` keyword (eg `struct student std1;`).

or // is not valid for commenting and you should use /**/ for commenting in ANSI C 89.

for example this C code is not valid in ANSI C 89:

```
struct student
{
  char* name;
};

enum number
{
  ODD,
  EVEN
};

void test()
{
  printf("Hello world!");
  int a, b; // Not valid in ANSI C 89, variables should declare at first line of blocks.
  student std1; // Not valid. It should be: struct student std1;
  struct student std2; // Valid.
  number n1 = ODD; // Not valid.
  enum number n2 = EVEN; // Valid.
}
```

I want to develope an application using ANSI C 89 and my question is:

What is the difference between ANSI C 89 and C that supports by C++?

Comment: are you talking about C99? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99

Comment: What do you mean by "C that supports by C++"? Are you talking about C99? Most compilers, even ones that support C99, will let you switch on "strict ANSI" options to warn or error in case of non-ANSI constructs being used.

Comment: What is "C that supports by C++"? C++ is a different language which has C as subset, but introduces many changes and differences.

Comment: @yi_H: No! I want to use ANSI C 89, because C99 is not supported by some comiplers (for example MS VC++).

Comment: There's no such thing as "C that is supported by C++". C++ is a language. C is another language. C++ permits a lot of things that are permitted in C89 -- most of them in fact. But there are loads of things that C++ allows and C doesn't not - keyword `class` for example, and `std::vector`. The C++ standard is much longer than the C standard, answers here cannot possibly list all the differences. Just learn C89 from a book such as K&R.

Comment: @glglgl: C++ supports C. I mean C subset of C++.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Stupid me. Deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The C subset of C++98/03 is modeled on C89 (obviously, since C99 wasn't out at the time); that of C++11 is modeled on C99. Nonetheless, the languages are quite different and the C subset of C++ isn't the same as the language C.

You're essentially asking "what's the difference between C++ and C", which isn't really a suitable question.

(For example, `sizeof('a')` is different in C and in C++, so if you're using MSVC++, knowing the C standard on which C++ was modeled doesn't help you at all).

Comment: +1 for "the C subset of C++ isn't the same as the language C." Ain't it the truth.

Comment: *You're essentially asking "what's the difference between C++ and C", which isn't really a suitable question.* - this means that your answer should be really a comment and the question should be closed, no?